# Pandas apply on groupby-frames and on full dataframe

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, apply, pandas-apply

Given a Pandas Dataframe I evaluate several variables via groupby expressions applying a customized function. Works fine (ignoring the second 0-index-column for the moment), but I would also like to apply the function to the full DataFrame.

```
xxx = pd.DataFrame([['A',1],['A',2],['B',3]],columns=(['cls','val']))
xxx

    cls val
0   A   1
1   A   2
2   B   3

def myagg(dat):
    vmax=dat.val.max()
    vmean=dat.val.mean()
    return pd.DataFrame([[vmax,vmean]],columns=(['MaxV','MeanV']))

xxx.groupby('cls').apply(myagg)
```

yields

```
        MaxV    MeanV
cls         
A   0   2   1.5
B   0   3   3.0
```

But xxx.apply(myagg) throws:

> AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'val'", 'occurred
>   at index cls')

I can create a constant dummy Variable and group by it to receive the result I wish - but there surely will be simpler ways to do it. Why does pandas think of the frame without groupby as a series, if type(xxx) returns pandas.core.frame.DataFrame? I'm on pandas 0.23.4; python 3.6.

```
xxx['dummy']='test'
xxx.groupby('dummy').apply(myagg)


         MaxV   MeanV
dummy           
test    0   3   2.0
```

Comment: If it is a series, you would need `vmax=dat.values.max()`.

Comment: @Kyle: why go to numpy via values - pd.Series([1,2,3]).max() works fine? My real myagg is way more involved and uses all of the frame, but the core problem seems  to be the group-logic, not the function.

Comment: Your error very clearly states the issue, that a series (which you are trying to apply your function to) doesn't have the attribute 'val'. This doesn't have anything to do with the groupby.

Comment: Thanks for getting back on this. Yes, I realize now, the apply on the dataframe-object is handed over/down to a pandas series by default, typically specified by the axis. For a groupby-Object the apply works on an iterator of dataframes and I thought, there might by a way to tweak groupby to generate some trivial iterator which yields only the dataframe itself.  That is what the additional 'dummy' column does - in an ugly way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems using a dummy function does the trick.

```
def dummy(dat):
    return 1

xxx.groupby(dummy).apply(myagg)
```

and the result is as in the question. No need to modify the dataframe.